# How to send pcap file to ethernet

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, pcap

I have a pcap file and need to send it to specific interface.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Tcpreplay](https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/). The interface to use can be specified [with the `--intf1` option](https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcpreplay-man.html).